# How to identify season by entering month? (Java)

Tags: java

Please type all code needed. Basically I need it so when you enter a month (e.g. January,February) the console gives the season that corresponds with the month.

Thanks.

Comment: What have you attempted so far? Be specific with your problem.

Comment: Please type all code needed?????  hahahahaha :D :D good one..

Comment: Post this on freelancing sites, they would be happy to do your homework for small fee ;)

Comment: @Ghetto Man: Again, you need to ask a *specific* engineering question that *specifies* exactly what you have tried, and what you are struggling with.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  If you want to use this site, then you need to use it in the right way. It is a site for serious programmers to ask technical questions.  It is NOT a "write my code for free" site, and I can guarantee that your Questions will be heavily downvoted and closed if you try to use it like that.  Please read the FAQ before you post your next Question.  It will save you from having your Questions "bashed" ... as you put it.

Comment: 12 months, 4 seasons. You will need 4 `if-statements` and a scanner to pick up user entered `int` between 1 and 12.

Comment: From a technical perspective, your question is either trivial (e.g. a `Map<String,String>` populated with values appropriate to your location) or impossible / meaningless.  The meaningless part is because there cannot be a mapping from months to seasons that works everywhere.  The seasons depend on the location, local culture ... and in some cases (i.e. cultures) on the actual weather.  The fact that you haven't considered this (apparently) suggests extreme insularity, or ... laziness.

Comment: For instance, if you asked someone in the Top End (of Australia) when autumn started, he/she might say, "we don't have autumn here - we have 'The Big Wet' and 'The Big Dry'".

Answer (score 3):

There is no mapping from months to seasons as March, June, September, December all span across two seasons. There are cultural and geographical issues (not as simple as Northern vs. Southern Hemisphere; in some tropics they merely refer to the "hot", "rainy" and "cool" seasons and don't use names like "Winter") and definitional issues (meteorological vs. astronomical seasons) as well. Since your request is impossible, there is no code to write. Since there is no code to write, I have written all of the code needed. Question, answer.

A few pro tips though. First, you might want to learn a little bit about writing specifications. It will help you ask better, more *specific* questions. Secondly, we don't type "all code" here. We answer clear, engaging, thoughtful, software engineering questions. Please keep this in mind in the future. Lastly, [The Java Programming Language by Ken Arnold et. al](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321349806) is a pretty great book for beginners. If you have any questions about any of the material in the book, keeping in mind the above comments on asking questions, we'd be happy to help you.

So, if you had come to us and said

> I am using the following definition of season [followed by a clear definition of the seasons]. Months correspond to seasons via the following rule [followed by a clearly specified unambiguous well-defined rule]. I have tried implementing this rule via the following [brief snippet of code] and I don't understand how to solve a problem I'm having [followed by a clear statement of the engineering issue that you are running into].

then we'd all be very eager to help you.

Comment: hey have to take care in what hemisphere is

Comment: @nachokk: You raise a good point, but it's not quite *that* simple.